# Xampp and file paths

Tags: php, html5, webserver, xampp, path

I'm having hard time with xampp, it really getting me crazy.
I have few installations of WordPress with Roots Template, which was loading without any css, js..etc. And the solution was to delete Boilerplate's default `.htaccess` and add:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/test_template/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/test_template/assets/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/test_template/assets/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now I'm facing the same problem but with HTML5 Boilerplate and Twitter-bootstrap, standard html5 file with no complex code. I've tried using:

```
 dirname(__FILE__);
```

And it still can't locate the files. Anybody had the same problem and found the solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does accessing the file directly work? eg. `http://example.com//wp-content/themes/test_template/assets/css/WHATEVER.css`

Comment: I got it work somehow, don't know what was o.O